# FFMPEG delaying the start of video when using between

Tags: video, ffmpeg

`ffmpeg -i "in.mp4" -i "./watermark.png" -f lavfi -i color=c=white:s=1080x1920 -filter_complex " [0:v]scale=2560:1440[ovr1], [1:v]scale=458:58[ovr2], [2:v][ovr1]overlay=-740:240:enable='between(t,2,7)'[int1], [int1][ovr2]overlay=W-500:H-100:enable='between(t,0,15)' [main] " -map "[main]" -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 27 -vb 20M -t 00:00:15 out.mp4`

This command takes my second input (watermark) it overlays it on my first input (video). It also scales both of them accordingly. It also sets the times to appear and disappear throughout the video.

The problem is `[2:v][ovr1]overlay=-740:240:enable='between(t,2,7)'[int1]` when I set my video input to appear between 2 seconds and 7 seconds. The result is as such, however, when it appears at the 2-second mark, the video is also starting at the 2-second mark when the video should start at its own 0-second mark within the new video.

How can I adjust the ffmpeg command above to start the video input at 2 seconds within the video but have it start at the input video's 0-second mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offset the timestamps of all streams of the main file.

`ffmpeg -itsoffset 2 -i "in.mp4" -i "./watermark.png" -f lavfi -i color=c=white:s=1080x1920 -filter_complex " [0:v]scale=2560:1440[ovr1], [1:v]scale=458:58[ovr2], [2:v][ovr1]overlay=-740:240:enable='between(t,2,7)'[int1], [int1][ovr2]overlay=W-500:H-100:enable='between(t,0,15)' [main] " -map "[main]" -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 27 -vb 20M -t 00:00:15 out.mp4`

For antiquated players that don't play nice with MP4 edit lists, fill the 2-second gap at the head of the audio stream with `-af aresample=async=1:first_pts=0`

Comment: Dude, you're always the best! I just figured out the `-itsoffset` command. I had to use it with `-ss`. The command I came up with is in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I just found the `-itsoffset` command and that works with setting the `-ss` to 0. Check out the command I came up with.

`ffmpeg -i "image.jpg" -itsoffset 1.99 -ss 0 -i "in.mp4" -i "./watermark.png" -f lavfi -i color=c=white:s=1080x1920 -filter_complex " [0:v]scale=864:576[ovr1], [1:v]scale=720:1280[ovr2], [2:v]scale=458:58[ovr3], [3:v][ovr1]overlay=108:672:enable='between(t,0,1.99)'[int1], [int1][ovr2]overlay=180:320:enable='between(t,1.99,6.99)'[int2], [int2][ovr3]overlay=W-500:H-100:enable='between(t,0,15)' [main] " -map "[main]" -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 27 -vb 20M -t 00:00:15 out.mp4`

This works well! Cheers!